# Communicating between views design patterns with events

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, eventaggregator, event-driven-design

event handlers are fine when you have a view that reference another view and listens its events, thats perfect for decoupling and reusability.

the problem though is sometimes I have views that is not referenced so I use Event Aggregator that is a global notification to know if something happened... but that seem not right when I just wanted to listen children views that I cant reference, something like bubbling events in the DOM hierarchy.

but let me say that I have a view hierarchy like:

- **ParentView**

  - ChildView

    - ChildView

      - **ModalView**

I wanted to know in the **ParentView** when the **ModalView** triggers an event... I cant use event bubbling because the **ModalView** is not in the same DOM hierarchy, so should I use Event Agregator in this case or something else? I really wanted that event bubble could fits in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use the DOM's hierarchy and you don't want to use an event aggregator my first instinct is that you need to build your own hierarchy into your views.

You can take a look at [backbone.courier](http://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.courier) for an idea of how to implement your own event bubbling system.

[Backbone.courier uses the DOM to detect parent views](http://github.com/rotundasoftware/backbone.courier#view_getparentview) but you can implement your own method for parent detection.

So it's doable without event aggregation or the DOM, but I think you'll end up creating and managing your own hierarchy. **Since we have the DOM already, this smells.** It would certainly make me question: "do I *really* need to bubble this event?".

For your example, the simplest solution might be to give your **ModalView** a reference to the **ParentView** and simply call the `parentView.listener()` when your even is fired on **ModalView**. Do you really need it to bubble through the children? Does this really need to be decoupled? It may be that you're being too restrictive when you assume you don't have a reference to your other view.

Those are questions I'd ask myself anyways. Though it may seem obvious it might be the best solution:

```
modalView.container = parentView;

modalView.myEventHandler = function(e) {
    this.container.myEventHandler(e);
}
```

Comment: thanks man, I think you are right.. in my case the best solution might be present a ModalView and reference the caller/presenter which makes sense... when the ModalView is done and triggers the presenter is called which is the deepest ChildView and it bubble triggers to notify the ParentView